# Share on Facebook / Twitter and confirm that it is shared

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I need to create a Share on Facebook / Twitter button. Such that when a user clicks that button and completes the share, I get an event in javascript fired.

Actually the user is rewarded something when they share my site on Facebook / Twitter. So I need an event fired when this is done.

Not when the user clicks the button, but when the share is submitted on Facebook / Twitter successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you want to do is not allowed on facebook. you cannot reward a user for sharing: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Actually I am talking about rewarding on my own site, not on facebook

so it goes like this:

- someone visits my site
- I have a share button
- if the visitor shares, he gets credits to be used on my site

Comment: me too ;) - it does not matter what the reward is.

Comment: see section 4.5 in the platform policy

Comment: users should share or like something because they WANT to, not because they get something for it. very important principle.

Comment: but it looks like some wordpress or magento plugins have this option, and I guess it is pretty much common that you get a credit for spreading the word, isnt it?

Comment: not allowed means not allowed, no matter if someone else does it ;) - and no, it is not common, it is very bad practice and spammy. that is why it is illegal on facebook.

Comment: ok luschn, I take your word for that :) and thanks for the answer, you can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is not allowed on Facebook. You cannot reward a user for sharing: https://developers.facebook.com/policy

see section 4.5:

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page,
>   enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t
>   incentivize other actions.

It is also very bad practice in general, users should like or share something because they want to, not because they would get something for it.